# How to pass parameter value of one build pipeline to another build pipeline as a input in azure devops using YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a build pipeline which is running with parameter value which is dynamic and once that build pipeline is completed then I should trigger another build pipeline which is in the same project passing input as a parameter from the first pipeline.

So in the first build pipeline I am running using a version as a parameter passing input and once the first pipeline runs successfully then it should trigger another build pipeline with the same parameter version value should be passed as a input.

I tried a lot but I couldn't do this. Much appreciated for your help.

In the First pipeline.yaml I have declared the version parameter like this and it will be dynamic value during run time I will pass different values.

parameters:

- name:version
  displayname:version
  type: string
  default: '1.0.0'

Comment: There's not going to be an easy way to do this. There is no shared state that persists after a pipeline runs other than published artifacts. Please explain what problem you're attempting to solve and perhaps someone can give you guidance on a better solution.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann , I have deploy pipeline which runs with version which is parameterised (will provide version dynamically/manually) and once that deploy pipeline is completed then It should trigger some test pipeline with the same version what is triggered for deploy pipeline. How to achieve this?

Comment: Why do these need to be separate pipelines? You can define multiple stages within a single pipeline.

Comment: @DanielMann , how to define multiple stages and also if integration pipeline fails then deploy pipeline also will result to fail right. I want both of them to be seperated.In this case how to pass parameters to  other pipeline and also if other pipeline is in different project how we can pass parameters to it ? Much appreciated for your response.